# Text length limit in logback logging

Tags: logging, cxf, logback

We are logging the application SOAP requests to the interfaces using the logback.xml configuration file. The SOAP requests are itself generated with the framework Apache CXF.

The configuration is given below.

```
<logger name="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="SOAPENVELOPLOGS" />
</logger>
```

The problem we are facing is when the SOAP request / response is of length more than 102410 characters, then the rest of text is not printed in the logs. Thus we have partial request / response being printed in the logs.

Would like to know is that this length limitation is in logback or Apache CXF.?
And that is there any work around for the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CXF.  The LoggingInInterceptor has a property on it to control the limit size of what it logs.   You would need to set the limit in there.

Comment: What property is that?

Answer (score 0):

You may set limit

```
LoggingInInterceptor lii = new LoggingInInterceptor(); 
lii.setLimit(limit);
```